# How to separate URL and save variable in wso2 ESB

Tags: web-services, restful-url, wso2-esb

I am working WSO2ESB Version 4.9.0. I want implement follow scenario in the wso2ESB.
In the scenario user call a web-service like:

```
http://192.168.0.1/getinfo/admin=1&userId=119008&codeOk=echo("user exist");&codeNoOK=echo("user not found);
```

the web-service check the user exist or not.
So my web-service just need this URL:

```
 http://192.168.0.1/getinfo/admin=1&userId=119008
```

and response  if user exist

```
<result>0</result>
```

and user not found

```
<result>1</result>
```

So when result=0 i want call another web-service and pass codeOk value "echo("user exist");:

```
http://192.168.0.200/code=echo("user exist");
```

and result=1 i want call :

```
http://192.168.0.200/code=echo("user not found);
```

I want this questions:

1-How to separate URL element ?

2-How to keep separate element for call later?

3-How to use Message Store and Message Processor in scenario ?

Thanks in advises.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to invoke two separate API calls. You can create API with two resources.

1. To check user existence (getinfo).
2. To send response back (code)

However, you can do that easily in one API call as well. if you could elaborate more on your requirement, I can give a try to answer to your query.

Comment: I want to do with one API because we need call web service sequentially and response of first web service is input for second web service.@Bhajan

Comment: @user6920966 Have you tried with callout mediator (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Callout+Mediator)?